# Unable to call Java Method from Groovy Script within SOAP UI

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I am facing a issue where I am trying to call a Java Method from within my Groovy SCript that lives in SOAP UI .

The script is able to see the java classes that have been packaged as  .jar file and placed on the SOAP UI's \bin\ext folder . This is the folder that SOAP UI wants you to put your custom classes in.

The purpose of the java class is that it calls ApachePoI API to read from a spreadsheet and return the values as a List . Each String element in the returned List represents a CSV of a SINGLE ROW of the .xls file.

***Groovy keeps complaining that it is not able to find the method though I can clearly see that it is present in the class . SOAP UI Error logs dont mention a thing..***

When I ran a simple test on these Java classes that I am trying to access, I can see that no errors are thrown and I am able to connect and read from the .xls file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as I am sure it may help someone .

When calling a Java Method from Groovy Script inside SOAP UI , please ensure that the Java class is public and methods are public as well . Also there are some issues with overloaded methods and constructors. Better to avoid these overloaded versions as SOAP UI  Fails Silently when encountering such issues. These issues are difficult to debug as you can't do the usual debugging from SOAP to Eclipse etc.

**

I hope this will help someone , as it has taken me several days and sleepless nights to solve this issue.

**

Comment: One can do remote debug in eclipse or any ide of user choice if debug options are added soapui invoking script.